# Tastypie Reverse Relation

Tags: django, tastypie

I am trying to get my api to give me the reverse relationship data with tastypie.

I have two models, DocumentContainer, and DocumentEvent, they are related as:

DocumentContainer has many DocumentEvents

Here's my code:

```
class DocumentContainerResource(ModelResource):
    pod_events = fields.ToManyField('portal.api.resources.DocumentEventResource', 'pod_events')
    class Meta:
        queryset = DocumentContainer.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'pod'
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get']

    def dehydrate_doc(self, bundle):
        return bundle.data['doc'] or ''

class DocumentEventResource(ModelResource):

    pod = fields.ForeignKey(DocumentContainerResource, 'pod')
    class Meta:
        queryset = DocumentEvent.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'pod_event'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

When I hit my api url, I get the following error:

```
DocumentContainer' object has no attribute 'pod_events
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I made a blog entry about this here: http://djangoandlove.blogspot.com/2012/11/tastypie-following-reverse-relationship.html.

Here is the basic formula:

## API.py

```
class [top]Resource(ModelResource):
    [bottom]s = fields.ToManyField([bottom]Resource, '[bottom]s', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = [top].objects.all()

class [bottom]Resource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = [bottom].objects.all()
```

## Models.py

```
class [top](models.Model):
    pass

class [bottom](models.Model):
    [top] = models.ForeignKey([top],related_name="[bottom]s")
```

It requires

1. a models.ForeignKey relationship from the child to the parent in this case
2. the use of a related_name
3. the top resource definition to use the related_name as the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.
Though I miss the related_name='[top]' attribute in ToManyField. This makes sure data is populated on create. See: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name

Answer (score 1):

Change your line in `class DocumentContainerResource(...)`, from

```
pod_events = fields.ToManyField('portal.api.resources.DocumentEventResource', 
                                'pod_events')
```

to

```
pod_events = fields.ToManyField('portal.api.resources.DocumentEventResource', 
                                'pod_event_set')
```

The suffix for `pod_event` in this case should be `_set`, but depending on the situation, the suffix could be one of the following:

- `_set`
- `_s`
- (no suffix)

If each event can only be associated with up to one container, also consider changing:

```
pod = fields.ForeignKey(DocumentContainerResource, 'pod')
```

to:

```
pod = fields.ToOneField(DocumentContainerResource, 'pod')
```

Comment: hmm, even after the changes, it didn't work for me. Now it says "'DocumentContainer' object has no attribute 'pod_event_set'"

Comment: @rookieRailer would you mind posting the related snippets from your models.py?

Comment: ForeignKey is an alias to ToOneField.